# How to use a Hidden Field inside a Custom Server Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a custom server control with client side abilities. To retrieve the state of the client on a Callback I want to include a hidden field. Unfortunately I neither know how to integrate the hidden field nor how to retrieve the data on a callback. I googled a lot but couldn't find anything that helped me.

So my questions are:
How do I implement a HiddenField into a custom server control? Render a plain html input field and give a static id? Use the asp.net HiddenField control?

How and when to retrieve the data from the control/field? Which event and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [CompositeControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.compositecontrol.aspx) to combine two or more server controls.

1. Add HiddenField control to Controls along with other controls overriding `CreateChildControls`
2. Render script to collect client side changes into HiddenField
3. When post back, collect the client side data from HiddenField.Value

[ASP.NET 4 in Practice - Composite Controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/197117/ASP-NET-4-in-Practice-Composite-Controls)